# Wildfly jms configuration

Tags: java, jboss, jms, ejb, wildfly

I'm having troubles with migration from old JBoss to Wildfly 14 (or some other latest version). 
Currently I'm stuck with JMS configuration. 
Here is the configuration:

- In `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:4.0">`I have added two queue definitions with the following code 
  `<jms-queue name="MyQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/MyQueue"/>
  <jms-queue name="OtherQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/OtherQueue"/>`
- In mentioned above subsystem definition I've added the following connection factory definition `<connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" />`
- In my application initialization code I have code which instantiates these jms queues.

In my class I have the following fields

```
private static final String JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI_NAME = "java:/ConnectionFactory";
@Resource(mappedName=JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI_NAME)
ConnectionFactory factory;
```

and in this class I have the following method:

```
public void openJmsSession() {
    try {
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        Context jndiContext = getInitialContext();
        queue =(Queue) jndiContext.lookup(JMS_MAIL_QUEUE_NAME);
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        logger.error("Naming exception during opening JMS session", e);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        logger.error("JMS exception during opening JMS session", e);
    }
}
```

Line `connection = factory.createConnection();` throws NPE because factory is null.

Comment: Are you actually wanting to define a custom connection factory or just destinations?

Comment: @WillT , I want to make my code work on new server instead of old one.
For JBoss the <mbean> items were used, but I don't know what to use for wildfly...

Comment: @WillT, In previous configuration there were only two queues defined and no custom connection factory. Is there any default connection factory? And if the answer  is "yes", - then how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approaches worked for me:

- **Solution via EJB** 
  To do this via EJB you should mark your bean with `@Stateless` and `@LocalBean` annotations. After adding this your bean will become a container-managed object and you can rely on it. Also while initial context creation you shouldn't specify any properties. Initial context creation should look like: 
  `private static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException 
  { return new` `InitialContext(); }`
- **Solution without EJB or other magic**

Add wildfly-ejb-client-bom, wildfly-jms-client-bom, wildfly-naming to your maven dependencies. In your client code use full JNDI names of JMS queues and connection factories. For example:

1. JMS queue: before `queue/MySuperJMSQueue`, after: `java:/jms/queue/MySuperJMSQueue`
2. JMS connection factory: before `ConnectionFactory`, after: `java:/ConnectionFactory`

Change your configuration file (in my case it's standalone-full.xml) by adding new JMS queue via the following line:

```
<jms-queue name="MySuperJMSQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/MySuperJMSQueue"/>
```

Change parameters which have been used for initial context instantiation:

```
private static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
    props.put( Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.as.naming.interfaces:org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    return new InitialContext(props);
}
```

After this manipulations you can do work with JMS. Just the example of opening JMS session:

```
        Context jndiContext = getInitialContext();
        ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup(JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI_NAME);
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        queue =(Queue) jndiContext.lookup(JMS_QUEUE_NAME);
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

For more details check the doc which is located by the following path: `<WildFly 14 home folder>\bin\client\README-EJB-JMS.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Having the following config:

```
<connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
```

I'm using this code:

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer helped. I don't get 'javax.naming.NameNotFoundException' anymore, but instead of it I'm getting 'NullPointerException' when I try to create a a jms session.

Comment: Can you update the question with the latest configuration? Please include the client code which is throwing the NPE as well as the stack-trace.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just need to access a JMS queue, there is probably a shorter way to do it (using the simplified api of JMS 2.0):

Config:

```
<jms-queue name="esb.inbound.test" entries="java:/jms/queue/esb.inbound.test"/>
```

Code:

```
@Resource(mappedName="java:/jms/queue/esb.inbound.test")
private Queue inboundQueue;
```

Comment: I have removed all my custom queues and connection factories, added queue definition to my standalone-full.xml and queue to my JMSClient. The result is: inboundQueue is null.

Comment: I use Eclipse to start Wildfly

Comment: Can you check whether WF is started with the correct profile (ie with "--server-config=standalone-full.xml" in your launch configuration in Eclipse) ?

Comment: I'm using eclipse configuration for this purpose.
Here is the [screenshot of my configuration](http://prntscr.com/lxcct9)

Comment: Also remember that resource injection only works for any *container-managed* object, such as a servlet, an enterprise bean, or a managed bean. Is it your case ?

Comment: The answer is "no", my class is not a _container-managed_ object. It's just a class. Even not public. Previous approach worked for old JBoss. I'll share a peace of code:
`Context jndiContext = getInitialContext();
ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup(JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI_NAME);
connection = factory.createConnection();     
queue =(Queue) jndiContext.lookup(JMS_MAIL_QUEUE_NAME);
session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);`

Comment: As I understand the JNDI lookup should be used. Am I right?
Maybe some namespace is missing in initial context instantiation?